# 'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, scons

Below is the error message when I run "scons" to compiler in windows7:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'cl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
scons: *** [out\windows-x86-MD-unicode-vs2008-rel\obj-static\src\featuresets\ada                                      pters\im-history\AddToChatRoomHistoryVisitor.obj] Error 1
scons: building terminated because of errors.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have added path to environment variables already, but still met this problem.

Below is the PATH info of environment variables:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v
1.0\;C:\Program Files\CREDANT\Shield v7.1\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Fil
es\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Python27;C:\cygwin64\bin
;C:\Python27\scons-2.3.1;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program File
s\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Progra
m Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microso
ft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\lib;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: And where is cl.exe located on your machine?  You surely have located it?  And verified that THAT location is in your path?

Answer (score 5):

The location of the cl.exe executable is not in the system **PATH** environment variable.

In other words the cmd.exe command line processor has been asked to run the cl.exe executable but it can't find it. It is either not in the **PATH** or not installed.

> I have added path to environment variables already, but still met this problem.

To test this open a command prompt and type in:

*cl.exe -?*

Answer (score 2):

SCons has logic to find the location of the visual studio install and set the path and other environment variables needed by visual studio tools by inspecting the registry and also default install locations.

If it's failing for you then you should produce a debug log and pastebin it somewhere for us to see.

use:

```
set SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG=%TEMP%\SCONS_MSVS_DEBUG.log
```

and then runs scons from the same shell.  The log will be in

> %TEMP%\SCONS_MSVS_DEBUG.log

You might also try the latest version of SCons 2.4.1 as I note there were some fixes for MSVS/MSVC in later versions. But in theory 2.3.1 should find Visual Studio 2010..

Comment: Curious why the -1?  Is there some mis-information here?

Answer (score 1):

Simply do window search for cl.exe, and add that path to PATH variable, save it. Close the existing open command and reopen it it before executing cl.exe. Hope this will work.

Comment: Incorrect. SCons doesn't pick up the PATH  from the shell.. This partly explains it. https://bitbucket.org/scons/scons/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#markdown-header-why-doesnt-scons-find-my-compilerlinkeretc-i-can-execute-it-just-fine-from-the-command-line  But for visual studio there's logic to look in the registry to find the installation location.

Comment: Additionally MSVC expects other environment variables to be defined to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and found a better way to fix it from @bdbaddog answer to get the debug log from `set SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG=%TEMP%\SCONS_MSVS_DEBUG.log` SCons seem to find the cl.exe

```
00073ms:MSCommon/vc.py:_check_cl_exists_in_vc_dir#588:checking for cl.exe at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe: 
00073ms:MSCommon/vc.py:_check_cl_exists_in_vc_dir#590:found cl.exe!:
```

And scons env `env['ENV']['PATH']` has the `cl.exe` path but it doesn't use it, So I just updated the session path using scons path like below and it worked

```py
os.environ['PATH'] = env['ENV']['PATH']
```