# SCons linking DLL cause a dependency cycle

Tags: c, windows, dll, scons

Here is a minimal example of my library. I have a library `lib.c` and an application `app.c` which use the library. And I'm using [Scons](https://scons.org/) to compile both the lib and the app. (the script is below)

- Initially, I was compiling the lib as a static library with `lib = env.Library(...)` and append the library to the env `env.Prepend(LIBS=[lib])` compile the app `env.Program(...)`, and everything working fine and no dependency errors.
- Now I try to compile my lib as a shared library. I added `__declspec(dllxxxx)` and compile the library with `lib = env.SharedLibrary(...)` and like before append the library to the env `env.Prepend(LIBS=[lib])` compile the app `env.Program(...)` and now I'm getting this dependency error

```
scons: *** Found dependency cycle(s):
  lib.dll -> lib.lib -> lib.exp -> lib.dll
  lib.lib -> lib.lib
  lib.exp -> lib.lib -> lib.exp
```

what am I doing wrong, and how to solve this?

#### lib.c

```c
__declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b);

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

#### app.c

```c
#include<stdio.h>
__declspec(dllimport) int add(int a, int b);

int main() {
    printf("%i\n", add(1, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

#### SConstruct

```py
import os

env = DefaultEnvironment(TARGET_ARCH = 'x86_64')
os.environ['PATH'] = env['ENV']['PATH'] ## for "cl.exe"

lib = env.SharedLibrary(
    target = 'lib',
    source = 'lib.c')
    
env.Prepend(LIBS=[lib])

env.Program(
    target = 'app',
    source = 'app.c')
```

Comment: Why do this "os.environ['PATH'] = env['ENV']['PATH'] ## for "cl.exe"
"... it shouldn't be needed?  Please add which version of msvc, which version of python, and which version of SCons you're using to your description above.

Comment: I can reproduce this, but something quite strange is going on. Even if dropping  back to `Library` instead of `SharedLibrary` I see an unexpected line in the output: `Creating library app.lib and object app.exp`. Why would it do that?

Comment: @bdbaddog I'm using VS2019 and python 3.7 . scons seems not to find the `cl.exe` similar case of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22954394/cl-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command/65397815#65397815)  if you know any better way, let me know

Comment: And I'm using Scons v4.0.1

Comment: SCons should find it without that. Please follow my posting from that other question and do this and attache the resutls.. set SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG=%TEMP%\SCONS_MSVS_DEBUG.log That will output information on how SCons is trying to find MSVC so we can figure out what's failing.

Comment: Jeez, like they did it on purpose.  The .exp file is an MSVC linker artifact that was designed to *solve* a circular dependency problem.  Unfortunately there is no linker option to stop it from being generated, you may have to be specific in LIBS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've added your example (modified to function as I beleive you're trying to achieve).

See notes in the SConstruct below.
Note that

```
env=DefaultEnvironment()
```

Is not the recommended usage.
Please use

```
env=Environment()
```

Also on my machine with freshly installed MSVC 2019, SCons found the compiler and by default produced X86_64 binaries. (SCons should default to the "native" arch if the compiler has support for that arch, otherwise it would try x86)

The msvc debug output from

```
set SCONS_MSCOMMON_DEBUG=%TEMP%\SCONS_MSVS_DEBUG.log
```

Would help to determine why you're having issues with SCons' native ability to find the MSVC install and configure it properly.
Also please consider joining us at https://discord.gg/bXVpWAy for further assistance.

See:
https://github.com/SCons/scons-examples/tree/master/shared-lib-program

SConstruct

```
# Skip initializing any tools in the DefaultEnvironment 
# as we're not using it.
DefaultEnvironment(tools=[])

env = Environment()

lib = env.SharedLibrary(
    target = 'a',
    source = 'lib.c')
    
# We list the library by it's base name 'a' and not a.dll, or liba.a because SCons
# will expand this to the appropriate platform/compiler dependent file name 
# and use the correct arguments to the linker to link against the shared library 'a'
# NOTE: We use LIBS here instead of env['LIBS']=['a'] as we're also building the
#       shared library above with the same Environment().
#       Having env.Prepend(LIBS=['a']) would cause the SharedLibrary() above to ALSO
#       try to link against shared library a. (Or on win32 file 'a.lib') and fail.
env.Program(
    target = 'app',
    source = 'app.c',
    LIBS=['a',])
```

app.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
__declspec(dllimport) int add(int a, int b);

int main() {
    printf("%i\n", add(1, 2));
    return 0;
}
```

lib.c

```
__declspec(dllexport) int add(int a, int b);

int add(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. and `cl.exe` works with scons. it wasn't last year so I added `cl.exe` to my environment and add `env.Append(ENV=os.environ)` to overcome.  now it's a bug in my code, I removed that line and build without it just worked.

Comment: Ahh. I bet the version you were using a year ago didn't recognize VS2019. Also there was some update to 2019 which broke scons msvc detection I think. Glad that worked!

Answer (score 0):

The loop comes from taking the result of the `SharedLibrary` and adding that to `LIBS`: the return from the call is a NodeList - containing the node representations of the three files `lib.dll`, `lib.lib`, `lib.exp`.  You can print the value of `lib` to see this.

Comment: you can append the name of the library to `LIBS`... `env.Prepend(LIBS="lib")`.